# Sharing rent information

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy

I want to create a website in UK where people can share what they pay for rent at the address they currently stay. This would be community-driven and work like glassdoor (a website for sharing your salary). It would help tenants decide if a landlord is asking too much and landlords to decide their rental price.

Would you see any legal problems with that? You would input an address and get a history of rental prices (if there are any in the database).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any legal issues with that. I can see landlords inserting a clause in the lease that prohibits it if your site becomes popular.

Comment: But then again, they would need to take legal action against their tenants, not the site, right? An NDA in a rental contract is something I would like to see 